# Theorem 5.11 in Schaum's _General Topology_: Topologies characterised by neighborhood systems

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

How to rigorously prove the following result?

> Let $X$ be a non-empty set and let there be assigned to each point $p \in X$ a class $\mathscr{A}_p$ of subsets of $X$ satisfying the following axioms:

> [A$_1$] $\mathscr{A}_p$ is not empty and $p$ belongs to each member of $\mathscr{A}_p$.

> [A$_2$] The intersection of any two members of $\mathscr{A}_p$ belongs to $\mathscr{A}_p$.

> [A$_3$] Every superset of a member of $\mathscr{A}_p$ belongs to $\mathscr{A}_p$.

> [A$_4$] Each member $N \in \mathscr{A}_p$ is a superset of a member $G \in \mathscr{A}_p$ such that $G \in \mathscr{A}_g$ for every $g \in G$.

> Then there exists one and only one topology $\mathscr{T}$ on $X$ such that $\mathscr{A}_p$ is the $\mathscr{T}$-neighborhood system of the point $p \in X$.

Here are a couple of relevant definitions:

> Let $X$ be a topological spaces, and let $p \in X$. Then a subset $N$ of $X$ is said to be a *nieghborhood* of point $p$ if there exists an open set $U$ of $X$ such that $p \in U \subset N$. The collection of all the neighborhoods of $p$ is said to be the *neighborhood system* of $p$ and is denoted by $\mathscr{N}_p$.

In any topological space $X$ and any point $p \in X$, the neighborhood system $\mathscr{N}_p$ of point $p$ of course satisfies all the conditions [A$_1$] through [A$_4$].

My Attempt:

> Let $\mathscr{T}$ be the following collection of subsets of $X$:
> $$
> \mathscr{T} = \big\{ G \colon \, G \subset X \mbox{ and } G \in \mathscr{A}_g \mbox{ for every } g \in G \big\}. \tag{1} 
> $$

> We show that this collection $\mathscr{T}$ is a topology on $X$.

> The empty set $\emptyset$ is in $\mathscr{T}$ vacuously. For every $x \in X$, since  $X$ is a superset of each member $N$ in $\mathscr{A}_x$, we can conclude from [A$_3$] above that $X \in \mathscr{A}_x$ and thus also that $X$ is in our collection $\mathscr{T}$.

Am I right?

> Let $\mathscr{T}_0$ be any subcollection of $\mathscr{T}$. Let us put
> $$
> S_0 := \cup_{S \in \mathscr{T}_0} S. 
> $$
> We show that this set $S_0$ is in $\mathscr{T}$. If $S_0 =\emptyset$, then we are done. So let $p \in S_0$. Then there exists a set $S_p \in \mathscr{T}_0$ such that $p \in S_p$. As $S_p \in \mathscr{T}$, so $S_p \in \mathscr{A}_p$, and since $S_0$ is a superset of $S_p$, therefore $S_0 \in \mathscr{A}_p$ for every point $p \in S_0$, thus showing that $S_0$ is in $\mathscr{T}$.

Am I right?

> Let $S_1, \ldots, S_n$ be any sets in $\mathscr{T}$, and let us put
> $$
> S := \cap_{i=1}^n S_i. 
> $$
> We show that this set $S$ is in $\mathscr{T}$. If $S = \emptyset$, then we are done. So let us assume that $p \in S$. Then, for each $i = 1, \ldots, n$, we have $p \in S_i$ and as $S_i$ is in $\mathscr{T}$, so we also have $S_i \in \mathscr{A}_p$, and thus from [A$_2$] above it follows that $S \in \mathscr{A}_p$. But as $p$ was an arbitrary point of $S$, so we can conclude that $S$ is in $\mathscr{T}$.

Am I right?

> Thus our collection $\mathscr{T}$ in (1) above is in fact a topology on $X$.

> Now we show that, for every point $p \in X$, $\mathscr{N}_p = \mathscr{A}_p$.

> Let $N \in \mathscr{N}_p$. Then there exists a set $S$ of $\mathscr{T}$ such that $p \in S \subset N$. Then by definition of $\mathscr{T}$ we have $S \in \mathscr{A}_p$ and since $N$ is a superset of $S$, we also have $N \in \mathscr{A}_p$ by virtue of [A$_3$] above, thus showing that $\mathscr{N}_p \subset \mathscr{A}_p$.

Am I right?

> Conversely, suppose that $A \in \mathscr{A}_p$. Then $p \in A$ by [A$_1$]  above and by [A$_4$] there exists a set $G \in \mathscr{A}_p$ such that $p \in G \subset A$ and $G \in \mathscr{A}_g$ for every $g \in G$, and this latter fact about this set $G$ implies that $G$ is in our topology  $\mathscr{T}$, and hence we also have $A \in \mathscr{N}_p$.

Am I right?

Is what I have done so far correct and accurate in each and every detail? If so, then is my presentation clear enough too?

If so, then what next? How to proceed from here? How to show that this topology $\mathscr{T}$ in (1) above is in deed unique?

PS:

> Finally, let $\mathscr{T}^\prime$ be any topology on our set $X$ such that, for every point $p \in X$, the $\mathscr{T}^\prime$-neighborhood system of $p$ equals $\mathscr{A}_p$.

> We show that
> $$ 
> \mathscr{T}^\prime = \mathscr{T}. \tag{2} 
> $$

Let $S$ be any set in $\mathscr{T}$. We can assume without any loss of generality that this set $S$ is non-empty. Then $S \subset X$ and $S \in \mathscr{A}_s$ for every $s \in S$. [Refer to (1) above.] Thus for every point $s \in S$, $S$ is a $\mathscr{T}^\prime$-neighborhood of $s$, which implies the existence of some $\mathscr{T}^\prime$-open set $U_s$ of $X$ such that $s \in U_s \subset S$, We therefore have
$$
S = \cup_{s \in S} U_s, 
$$
which being a union of some sets in $\mathscr{T}^\prime$ is also in $\mathscr{T}^\prime$. Thus it follows that
$$
\mathscr{T} \subset \mathscr{T}^\prime. \tag{3} 
$$

Am I right?

> Conversely, suppose that $S$ is in $\mathscr{T}^\prime$. Then for every point $s \in S$, the set $S$ itself is a $\mathscr{T}^\prime$-neighborhood of $s$, that is, $S \in \mathscr{A}_s$ for every $s \in S$ and $S \subset X$ of course, thus showing that $S$ is in $\mathscr{T}$. Thus it follows that
> $$
> \mathscr{T}^\prime \subset \mathscr{T},
> $$
> which together with (3) above yields (2).

Am I right?

Is the proof now complete in each and every respect? Or, are there some necessary bits still missing?